# Qt Creator no member named stackedWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt5.2

I've just designed my ui in the QT-Creator and, as the main application is based on two panels, I decided to use the StackedWidget for "change the layout" without opening a new window.

So, I added a QTStackedWidget named: stackedWidget (as default).

The problem is in mainwindow.cpp, I added a custom SLOT that contain:

```
ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);
```

when I build this the compiler says:

> mainwindow.cpp:25: error: no member named 'stackedWidget' in 'Ui::MainWindow'
>      ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);
>      ~~  ^

also in the qt-creator itself I was unable to attach a signal to the stackedWidget because it doesn't show to me the setCurrentIndex SLOT...

any advice?

Please note that I'm a noob with C++ I just used Qt a couple of years ago with PyQt4.

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

private slots:
    void showOtherPage();
    void showMainPage();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainiwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qDebug() << "MainWindow - Debug Mode ON";
    connect(ui->btnOther, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(showOtherPage()));
}

void MainWindow::showOtherPage()
{
    qDebug() << "Showing Other Page";
    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);
}

void MainWindow::showMainPage()
{
    qDebug() << "Showing Main Page";
    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: can you post a bit more code of how the class is defined?

Comment: You're right. Keep in mind that I'm working only with Qt-Creator and that's 70% of automatic-code.

Comment: Check your ui file (or with designer) if you have stackedWidget. Maybe you renamed it and you didn't pay attention.

Comment: row 65:  <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget">
row 66:    <property name="geometry">

Comment: Try: clean, run qmake, build.

Comment: Tried, but nothing changed

Answer (score 9):

I had a very similar issue. 
One of the UI actions was defined as the others and used.
I had a `ui has no member named xyz` compilation error for this one only, without possible explanation.

I could solve it by unchecking/checking the `Shadow build` option in the project compilation options!

Hope it saves someone the 30 minutes I just lost :)

Answer (score 1):

Faced the very same issue today. Recreating the project does work, though I've found a solution that won't make one rewrite everything :) Run it in Debug. Once you've done it, problem's solved.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new project fixed it... I don't know why, I'm still looking for an explanation.

I started a new project, created the stackedWidget, and tested the code for the page-switching... it just simply works... and I still do not know WHY the other one fail to build...

Checked again and again names and everything.

Answer (score 0):

I tried cleaning project and running qmake without any luck. I then drilled down into the project folder and deleted the ui_***.h file and everything started working. Might have had to do with the fact Visual Studio generated that file and I was working on another computer with Qt Creator for the same project.